# How to remove permission set from deactivated user using apex

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce1-app, scheduled-apex

Inactivate users when their last working day is today.
Capture the users last working day in a custom field on user.
Batch will run every day once.

1. Remove the permission sets assigned to the user being deactivated
2. Mark the user inactive.
3. Send mail to a set of configurable email id with the users deactivated.

what optimal approach should I follow cause i am thinking i should make a batch class in batch class i should set the user inactive and run an apex trigger if its inactive remove the permission set from it and send the mail using apex batch

Comment: Is there a reason you need to remove the permission sets assigned to the users? As long as they're deactivated then the permission sets assigned to them won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

For remove permission set from user you can query on PermissionSetAssignment Object in salesforce [[Link]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm)

For Example :

```
for(PermissionSetAssignment psa :[SELECT Id 
                                         FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
                                         WHERE AssigneeId=:YOUR_USER_ID]){
                                            //add into list and delete it
        }
```